# Distribuição randômica em listas com python

Tags: python, random

Tenho uma lista:

```
li = [0, 0, 2313, 1221, 0, 1333, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

e outra lista de listas, onde:

A lista de listas chama-se disciplinas (abaixo). As listas que estão dentro de disciplinas, estão especificadas abaixo também:

```
#essas são as listas que estão dentro de disciplinas:
cs = [2313, 2214, 2120]
gav = [1101, 1103, 1104]
icc = [3201, 3304, 3209]
comp = [4101, 4203, 4409, 4559]

#lista de listas
disciplinas = [cs, gav, icc, comp]
```

Eu preciso escolher por sorteio da lista **disciplinas** um valor (`cs` ou `gav` ou `icc` ou `comp`). Pensei em usar o método `choice()`. Após o valor ser escolhido aleatoriamente, devo remover de disciplinas e adicionar em **`li`** em uma posição aleatória de **`li`**, somente onde for zero. Tenho de fazer isso, enquanto disciplinas for diferente de nulo.

**OBS:** devo adicionar o valor de disciplinas apenas um em seguido do outro, nunca isolado, de modo que fique assim, por exemplo:

```
li = [cs, cs, 2313, 1221, 0, 1333, 66, icc, icc, gav, gav]
```

Já consegui encontrar uma forma de distribuir nas posições onde encontrar zero (no exemplo abaixo, substituí 0 por 1), de forma que só permita colocar o item se o item_atual e item_atual+1 OU item_atual e item_atual-1 forem iguais a zero:

```
l = [0, 0, 2313, 1221, 0, 1333, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0]
lCount = len(l)
next1 = False
for i in range(0, lCount-1):
    if(l[i] == 0 and l[i+1] == 0):
        l[i] = 1
        l[i+1] = 1
        next1 = True
    if(next1): # ultimo elemento caso seja 0 seguido de outro (next1 definido no ultimo loop do ciclo)
        l[-1] = 1
print(l) # [1, 1, 2313, 1221, 0, 1333, 66, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Muito obrigado!

Comment: Somente onde for um 0 seguido de outro certo? É como a sua pergunta anterior? Sempre que o seja um 0 seguido de outro 0 os dois são alterados para esses valores de disciplinas

Comment: H+a um problema com "devo remover de disciplinas e adicionar em li", porque se remover a disc da lista disciplinas cada vez que adicionar uma a l, então só vamos poder fazer isso quatro vezes, porque a lista disciplinas vai ficar vazia ao quarto 0 seguido

Comment: Corretíssimo Miguel, mas não tem problema se for executado apenas 4 loops nesse caso. O objetivo é esse mesmo, porque trata-se de um algoritmo genético e essa parte que está sendo feita é para gerar um indivíduo. Irei fazer uma lista que armazena todos os indivíduos gerados para gerar a população :D

Comment: Ha mas tendo em conta o resultado final que deseja e publicou na pergunta `li = [cs, cs, 2313, 1221, 0, 1333, 66, icc, icc, gav, gav] `, isto não é executado só 4 vezes

Comment: Verdade, mas é que dei apenas como exemplo para explicar que são dependentes entre eles, por ex: só posso adicionar uma disciplina em seguida da outra, mas nunca ela isolada. Só que preciso que quando ela for adicionada randomicamente na lista li, ela seja removida de disciplinas, não sei se deu pra entender? O.o muito obrigado! :D

Comment: Sim deu, mas pense comigo, nesse exemplo que deu existem 6 locais onde precisamos fazer a inserção certo? Mas nas nossas disciplinas só exsitem 4... O que acontecia nos ultimos 2 0 em `l` seguidos?

Comment: Perfeito amigo, excelente observação ^^ =) no meu caso, eu não coloquei aí para não ficar código demais, mas eu tenho na verdade um vetor com 80 posições de zeros. E outro vetor disciplinas com 50 posições. Vai acabar sobrando lugar, mas é esse o intuito mesmo :D tem como fazer então isso? Já no loop remove de disciplinas?

Comment: Claro que sim, então no momento em que já não existem disciplinas não adiciona mais certo? e vai removendo à medida que vai acrescentando certo? Vou fazer

Comment: Feito em baixo @Allan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exatamente com choice dá para fazer, deve importar o modulo random:

```
import random

cs = [2313, 2214, 2120]
gav = [1101, 1103, 1104]
icc = [3201, 3304, 3209]
comp = [4101, 4203, 4409, 4559]

disciplinas = [cs, gav, icc, comp]
l = [0, 0, 2313, 1221, 0, 1333, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0]

randDisc = [] # armazenamos os resultados sorteados para mais tarde remove-los da lista disciplinas
lCount = len(l)
next1 = False
for i in range(0, lCount-1):
    if(len(disciplinas) > 0):
        disc = random.choice(disciplinas)
        if(l[i] == 0 and l[i+1] == 0):
            l[i] = disc
            randDisc.append(disc)
            disciplinas.remove(disc)
            next1 = True
        elif(next1):
            l[i] = disc
            randDisc.append(disc)
            disciplinas.remove(disc)
            next1 = False
    else:
        break

print(l) # [[1101, 1103, 1104], [2313, 2214, 2120], 2313, 1221, 0, 1333, 66, [3201, 3304, 3209], [4101, 4203, 4409, 4559], 0, 0]
print(disciplinas) # []
```

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo Miguel! Show!

Comment: Hehe show de bola. De nada @Allan

Comment: Um adendo ao que foi feito: ao imprimir o vetor todas as posições estão preenchidas com zero. Pense em um vetor com tamanho 80 todo preenchido de zeros: li = [0] * 80

Comment: Em média são uns 50 valores que devo adicionar a esse vetor preenchido de zeros. Mas nem todas as posições do vetor li devem ser preenchidas, já que tenho 50 valores e 80 posições vazias (com zero). Esse código está adicionando em todas as posições de li. Como eu poderia corrigir isso?

Comment: Não percebi. O objectivo é trocar em `l` todos os elementos cujo são 0 e o elemnto anterior também é 0 certo? Por um elemnto random da lista `disciplinas`

Comment: Ou seja se tivessemos: `l = [0,0,0,5]` ficava `l = [randomDisc,randomDisc,randomDisc,5]`. Certo?

Comment: Não haha é assim: o vetor disciplinas é a lista de disciplinas, na vdd uma lista de lista. Veja ali no seu código que só depois de toda a execução, foram removidos os sorteados de disciplinas. Estou tentando fazer com que durante o laço, aqueles que forem sorteados e adicionados ao randDisc já sejam removidos da lista de disciplinas. As posições da lista l que não forem preenchidas por um valor da lista disciplinas, devem permanecer zero.  Entendeu? =)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `random` para fazer o sorteio do valor e da nova posição a ser inserida. Caso a posição seja diferente de **0**, tente de novo.

```
import random as r
li = [None, None, 65123, 2223, 4536, None, None, None]

while(len(disciplina) > 0):
    p_rem = r.randint(0, len(disciplina)-1)
    v_rem = disciplina[p_rem]
    disciplina.remove(v_rem)

    while True:
        li_add = r.randint(0, len(li)-1)
        if not li[li_add]:
            li[li_add] = v_rem
            break
```

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo Brumazzi DB!